# This code for applying a CBR filter to an ASF Writer doesn't work, why?

Tags: filter, directshow, asf, writer

I am trying to apply a CBR profile to an ASF Writer to reduce latency for a video/audio streaming.

This is what I've done till now:

1. Using Media Encoder, I generated a
   default CBR profile
2. Saved the profile to a prx file

Used this code to apply the profile to the ASF Writer:

```
 // Initialize a new Profile Manager
 IWMProfileManager* pIPM = 0;
 WMCreateProfileManager(&pIPM);

FILE * file = fopen("lowprofile.prx", "rb");

 fseek(file, 0, SEEK_END);
 long length = ftell(file);
 fseek(file, 0, SEEK_SET);

 wchar_t * buffer = new wchar_t[length];
 size_t numRead = fread(buffer, sizeof(wchar_t), length, file);
 buffer[numRead] = NULL;
 fclose(file);

 IWMProfile* pProxProfile = 0;
 hr = pIPM->LoadProfileByData(buffer, &pProxProfile);

 // Set the profile for the writer
 CComQIPtr<IConfigAsfWriter2> pConfigWriter;
 pConfigWriter = m_pWMASFWritter;

 hr = pConfigWriter->SetParam(AM_CONFIGASFWRITER_PARAM_DONTCOMPRESS, TRUE, 0);

 hr = pConfigWriter->ConfigureFilterUsingProfile(pProxProfile); // THIS LINE FAILS, hr = E_FAIL

 hr=m_pGraph->AddFilter(m_pWMASFWritter,L"ASF Writter");
 if(FAILED(hr)) 
  return FALSE;

//etc..
```

What's wrong with this code? I misunderstood something??

Unfortunately for me there's no code in the media format sdk nor available on the internet to help me applying such filter. I am trying to read carefully the documentation available on msdn, but it's surely not as clear as a good code sample.

Can someone give me a hint please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That looks ok, I have code close to that working just fine - try and set the profile file to use standard audio/video codecs to see if the code works then just to pinpoint the problem and/or comment out the `SetParam` call.

Also make sure you first add the AsfFileWriter  to the graph, then configure it and finally connect the graph. You currently add it only after configuring it - again, that might work, it's just not the order I have running and definitely works.

Comment: Thank you brokenglass, it was incredibly the adding first ASF Writer to the graph and THEN configuring with the right profile. Now works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Here you are calculating the filesize in bytes:

```
fseek(file, 0, SEEK_END);
long length = ftell(file);
fseek(file, 0, SEEK_SET);
```

But then you treat it as the size in chacacters:

```
wchar_t * buffer = new wchar_t[length];
size_t numRead = fread(buffer, sizeof(wchar_t), length, file);
buffer[numRead] = NULL;
```

You can use the following fix:

```
long length = ftell(file) / sizeof(wchar_t);
```